# MAXIMA CAS input has stopped working

Tags: maxima

I've been using MAXIMA CAS for a while now and I've recently ran into a problem. When I open MAXIMA the input line now begins with an upside question mark and the spacebar won't work either has anyone ever had this problem?

Comment: It sounds like the character encoding is configured incorrectly. What else can you tell us about this problem? What system and version of Maxima are you using?

Comment: So I've been using the latest version. I tried installing an older version but the problem persists. I'm using latest software Mac OS. 
So the upside down q mark is still there. Another thing, If I try an underscore it appears as a dot instead. Have you ever encountered this?

Comment: Hmm, it certainly appears that the characters you type are being interpreted incorrectly. I don't use a Mac so I don't have any specific advice for you. A couple of things to try: (1) Try posting a question to a Mac user forum -- people there might know something about the character problem. (2) Post a message to the Maxima mailing list. See: https://lists.sourceforge.net/lists/listinfo/maxima-discuss I know some people on that list use Mac.

Comment: Excellent. It's strange it did work perfectly well for quite a while. I will ask in the MAXIMA mailing list.

Comment: If it was working and then it stopped, maybe there was some change in the configuration of your system.

Comment: Is there a way to reset character encoding do you know?

Comment: Well, the only thing that I know to try is to set an environment variable when executing Maxima, something like: `$ LC_CTYPE=<something> maxima` i.e. put LC_CTYPE= on the command line before `maxima`. Here `<something>` is perhaps `C` or `en_US.UTF-8` or something else. Try searching the web for `setlocale` also. But as I say, I don't have a Mac so I'm really just guessing.